# Odoo web view header title & breadcrumbs

Tags: templates, header, client, odoo

I create a web module that display a simple iframe in the view.
But it shown in all the oe_application section.

http://s26.postimg.org/yudzwfupl/sufempty.png

I want to keep the header displayed, somehow like this:

http://s26.postimg.org/3opaly8mx/suf.png

I tried to extend template managing the header in my template like this:

```
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-id="ViewManager" t-extends="web.template.ViewManager">
    </t>
    <t t-name="graphics_frame">
        <t t-call="ViewManager">
        </t>
        <iframe t-att-src="widget.url" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></iframe>
    </t>
</templates>
```

But some variables used in the template (widget.flags) are not defined.

Please, any suggestion how to show the header from client side ?

I need to keep the breadcrumbs and the title displayed.